# How to get Documents which name starts with "ab"

Tags: java, mongodb, filter

I want to filter a collection which name field starts with "ab".

How I can write it using Filters e.g.

```
Filters.regex("name","regex pattern")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find in **collection** with name starting with 'ab' then the query is:

```
//For case sensitive
db.collection.find({ 'name':/^ab/ });

//For case insensetive -pass the i flag
db.collection.find({ 'name':/^ab/i });
```